# Why isn't this code being formatted properly?

Tags: support, code-formatting, editing-help

So I made a [revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36635233/revisions) to a poorly formatted post, which had most of its words in a code block. I didn't realize it when I was editing, but somehow, four spaces is not creating code blocks. (One code block is fine, for whatever reason.)

I went back and tried to fix the code, but it's not working. I tried putting a blank line to separate it from non-code, and also <kbd>command</kbd> +<kbd>k</kbd> formatting the code, but it's just not working.

Why is this happening? Can anyone fix it (OP seems to have accepted the edit)?

It's Python code, so it really needs to be a code block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently there were some undisplayable characters ([Line separator](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2028/index.htm) I think) in the post which weren't playing nicely with the parser. I copied the post into a text editor which showed them, removed them all, and pasted it back, and it seems to be working correctly once they were removed.

Comment: Thanks! I was afraid to mess with the spaces because it's Python. It would be nice if the SO editor had an option to display non-printables.

Comment: Yes, the byte sequence was 0xE2 0x80 0xA8. [Unicode "U+2028  LINE SEPARATOR" is 0xE2 0x80 0xA8 as UTF-8](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8192&number=128).