# Can we view non-printable characters in the editor?

Tags: feature-request, editor

The SO editor does not deal well with non-printable characters. [They mess up code formatting.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321086/why-isnt-this-code-being-formatted-properly)

There should be a way to view non-printable characters in the editor. Obviously not all the time, but allow it to be toggled.

It might also be good to be able to see this when reviewing edits.

Comment: Yes please! As someone very active on [Programming puzzles and code golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) that would help a **lot** for some esolangs.

Comment: Is this not a job for a browser plug-in? Or you can copy/paste into a real text editor.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It's different when it's not your code. There are also [security concerns](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39118/how-can-i-protect-myself-from-this-kind-of-clipboard-abuse)